# Start-Process Issues running WsusUtil.exe

Tags: powershell, syntax-error, try-catch, start-process

I have a really simple issue that I can't seem to figure out...

I have a powershell script to update WSUS data and then export it so I can burn it to CD for our secure environment, everything works great, except running the wsusutil.exe I get an error when trying to define arguments.

Here's the original script

```
$nicedate = Get-Date -UFormat %m-%d-%Y

Write-Output("Starting wsusutil...")
Set-Location "C:\Program Files\Update Services\Tools"
Start-Process wsusutil.exe export "E:\$nicedate-export.xml.gz" "E:\$nicedate-export.log"
Write-Output("wsusutil completed")
```

but the error I get is...

> "Start-Process : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'E:\Metadata\04-14-2021-export.xml.gz'."

So I modified the code to just do:

```
Write-Output("Starting wsusutil...")
"C:\Program Files\Update Services\Tools\WsusUtil.exe" export "E:\Metadata\$nicedate-export.xml.gz" "E:\Metadata\$nicedate-export.log"
Write-Output("wsusutil completed")
```

but it still isn't kicking off the service. I just need to run an export on the WsusUtil.exe and define the output of the log and zip. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

NOTE: After this is tested, I plan on turning this line into a try-catch for future use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a moment to review `Start-Process` shall we?

the `Start-Process` cmdlet syntax as described by the help page is:

```
SYNTAX
    Start-Process [-FilePath] <String> [[-ArgumentList] <String[]>] [-Credential <PSCredential>] [-LoadUserProfile]
    [-NoNewWindow] [-PassThru] [-RedirectStandardError <String>] [-RedirectStandardInput <String>]
    [-RedirectStandardOutput <String>] [-UseNewEnvironment] [-Wait] [-WindowStyle {Normal | Hidden | Minimized |
    Maximized}] [-WorkingDirectory <String>] [<CommonParameters>]

    Start-Process [-FilePath] <String> [[-ArgumentList] <String[]>] [-PassThru] [-Verb <String>] [-Wait] [-WindowStyle
    {Normal | Hidden | Minimized | Maximized}] [-WorkingDirectory <String>] [<CommonParameters>]
```

How you are running your current code is looking for positional parameters to match each of the spaces after `wsutil.exe` even though you need those as arguments. To actually use those as arguments, remember to use the `-ArgumentList` parameter. So instead of

```
Start-Process wsusutil.exe export "E:\$nicedate-export.xml.gz" "E:\$nicedate-export.log"
```

it becomes

```
Start-Process wsusutil.exe -ArgumentList 'export "E:\$nicedate-export.xml.gz" "E:\$nicedate-export.log"'
```

or for more safety,

```
Start-Process wsusutil.exe -ArgumentList @('export', '"E:\$nicedate-export.xml.gz"', '"E:\$nicedate-export.log"')
```

Your second attempt,

```
Write-Output("Starting wsusutil...")
"C:\Program Files\Update Services\Tools\WsusUtil.exe" export "E:\Metadata\$nicedate-export.xml.gz" "E:\Metadata\$nicedate-export.log"
Write-Output("wsusutil completed")
```

is attempting to read `"C:\Program Files\Update Services\Tools\WsusUtil.exe" export "E:\Metadata\$nicedate-export.xml.gz" "E:\Metadata\$nicedate-export.log"` as a string, not a command. If I run

```
"C:\Program Files\Update Services\Tools\WsusUtil.exe"
```

in powershell, the output will be equivalent to if I ran

```
Write-Output "C:\Program Files\Update Services\Tools\WsusUtil.exe"
```

If you are trying to call a file from filepath, remember to use the calling character, `&`

```
& "C:\Program Files\Update Services\Tools\WsusUtil.exe" export "E:\Metadata\$nicedate-export.xml.gz" "E:\Metadata\$nicedate-export.log"
```

Comment: Thank you for this information! I will test out some of the methods that you provided. I'm curious, what is safer about using ``` @('information') ``` vs just ``` 'information' ``` in the ArgumentList trigger? I apologize for the simple question, I am still trying to better my knowledge of powershell

Comment: No worries, sometimes doing the normal  `"args with space delim"` doesn't work and when you have arguments with both `'` and `"`, you will need to escape such. In the end both of them work the same most of the time and it all comes down to a matter of preference, but if the `"` doesn't work, always try the other one as well :-)

Comment: Awesome! Thank you sir. Works perfectly.